Chrome Devtools showing gzip response in HEX
For some reason Chrome devtools started to show requests with gzip content in a HEX editor view like on response tab. That's very annoying... is there a way to disable this view and show plain text/json data?
devtools network tab screenshot
I search in the devtools options something related but found nothing. I would like to see the data in preview or response tab as plain text/json like.

This is a bug. You can report it in https://crbug.com if it's not yet fixed in Chrome Canary.
